# Which Ruby on Rails gem should be best used for importing the user data from facebook into database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, import, rubygems

I want to build a Ruby on Rails application for which I need to import all the data (excepts posts, shares and messages)  of a Facebook user.
This will be my first RoR app on my own (newbie) and really not able to find the right gem for my requirements.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to authenticate from **facebook** and then you can use the `koala gem` to get any details/post on facebook.
For authentication ,you must use [omniauth facebook gem](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook).Once you are authenticated,you can interact with facebook to get any details you want using [koala gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/) where you can use the access token received after authentication from omniauth facebook gem.
You can google around and get the idea how to auththenticate from **facebook** and have a look in [361-facebook-graph-api Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/361-facebook-graph-api).
...HOPE THIS HELPS

do watch this as well:- [facebook authentication in rails](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication?view=asciicast)